# How to ensure Ember is saving variable state on reload

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm creating and saving a form using Ember but when I reload the page the toggle keeping track of whether the form has been submitted or not resets to false.

I have a page where the default text is 'You have no account linked'. I then have a button that when pressed displays a form for the user to fill out information . When they click submit and save their information, the form disappears and renders some text about their account. When I reload the page however the text renders to the default 'You have no account linked', and when I click the submit form button, their information is populated in the form fields. How can I ensure that when the page is reloaded the text about the user account is displayed?

This is the controller for the page

```
export default Controller.extend({
  isToggled: false,
  emailConnected: false,
  actions: {
    submitImap(mailbox, toggle, email) {
      this.get('ajax').request(`/api/accounts/${this.session.account.id}/mailboxes/imap`, {
        method: 'POST',
        data: mailbox
      })
        .then(() => Utils.notify("IMAP settings saved.", 'success'))
        .catch(() => Utils.notify("Error saving IMAP account. Try again", 'error'));
      this.send('contract', toggle);
      this.send('expand', email);
    },
    disconnectIMAP(mailbox, property, email) {
      this.get('ajax').request(`/api/accounts/${this.session.account.id}/mailboxes/imap`, {
        method: 'DELETE',
        data: {
          user_id: mailbox.user_id
        }
      }).then(() => {
        this.set(property, { smtp: {}});
      })
        .then(() => Utils.notify("IMAP removed. ", 'success'))
        .catch(() => Utils.notify("Error removing IMAP account", 'error'));
      this.send('contract',email );
    },
    expand: function(toggle) {
      this.set(toggle, true)
    },
    contract: function(toggle) {
      this.set(toggle, false)
    }
  }
});
```

This is the template handling the form submission

```
<h3>IMAP/SMTP</h3>
{{#if emailConnected}}

  {{#if isToggled}}
    <p> Edit your IMAP settings below </p>
  {{else}}
    <p>
      You currently have IMAP account <strong>{{imapMailbox.username}}</strong>
      connected for messaging.
    </p>
    <button  {{action "disconnectIMAP" imapMailbox 'imapMailbox' 'emailConnected' }} class = 'btn btn-danger'>Disconnect</button>
  {{/if}}

{{else}}
  <p>
    You currently do not have an account linked for messaging.
  </p>
{{/if}}

{{#if isToggled}}

  <form name='imap' class='modern-form full-width' {{action 'submitImap' imapMailbox 'isToggled' 'emailConnected' on="submit" }}>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <h4>IMAP</h4>
        <div class='form-group'>
          <label>
            Host
          </label>
          {{input type='text' required=true name='address' value=imapMailbox.address class='form-control'}}
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
          <label>
            Port
          </label>
          {{input type='text' required=true name='port' value=imapMailbox.port class='form-control'}}
        </div>
        <div class='form-check'>
          {{input type='checkbox' name='ssl' checked=imapMailbox.ssl class='form-check-input'}}
          <label for='ssl'>
            SSL
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class='form-check'>
          {{input type='checkbox' name='starttls' checked=imapMailbox.starttls class='form-check-input'}}
          <label>
            TLS
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
          <label>
            Username
          </label>
          {{input type='text' required=true name='username' value=imapMailbox.username class='form-control'}}
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
          <label>
            Password
          </label>
          {{input type='password' required=true name='password' value=imapMailbox.password class='form-control'}}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <h4>SMTP</h4>
        <div class='form-group'>
          <label>
            Host
          </label>
          {{input type='text' required=true name='smtp_address' value=imapMailbox.smtp.address class='form-control'}}
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
          <label>
            Port
          </label>
          {{input type='text' required=true name='smtp_port' value=imapMailbox.smtp.port class='form-control'}}
        </div>
        <div class='form-check'>
          {{input type='checkbox' name='smtp_ssl' checked=imapMailbox.smtp.ssl class='form-check-input'}}
          <label for='ssl'>
            SSL
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class='form-check'>
          {{input type='checkbox' name='smtp_starttls' checked=imapMailbox.smtp.enable_starttls_auto class='form-check-input'}}
          <label>
            TLS
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
          <label>
            Username
          </label>
          {{input type='text' required='true' name='smtp_username' value=imapMailbox.smtp.user_name class='form-control'}}
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
          <label>
            Password
          </label>
          {{input type='password' required='true' name='smtp_password' value=imapMailbox.smtp.password class='form-control'}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class='btn btn-success'>
      Save
    </button>
    <button {{action 'contract' 'isToggled'}} class = 'btn btn-danger'>
      Cancel
    </button>
  </form>

{{else}}
  <button {{action 'expand' 'isToggled'}} class= 'btn btn-success'>
    Connect email
  </button>
{{/if}}
```

Right now, if I submit the form the behavior is as expected, displaying the current username of the account, but on reload the emailConnected variable resets to false and the default of 'you have no account connected' is present and when I click the form the values are populated.

Comment: Are you using any library like `ember-simple-auth` to implement `authentication/authorization` in your application?

Comment: No i am not using a library like that

Comment: What does your `this.session.account` contain ? Do you maintain any session in the client or server side ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `reload` the page (or) `switch` to a different route, the controller's property `isToggled` will reset to its initial state (i.e) to `false` in your case.

If you want to maintain the state and make use of the property `isToggled` at various parts of your application, you can use [ember service](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.8.0/applications/services/)

But in your case, you want to maintain the property state even after the page `reloads`. ember service doesn't maintain the state after the page reloads.

Here comes the use of browsers [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

So, in your case -

1) store the value of the property `isToggled` in browsers `localStorage`

```
import { computed } from '@ember/object';

export default Controller.extend({
  isToggled: computed(function () {
    // when the user visits the page for the very first time,
    // isToggled value is set to false,
    // from next time it gets the value from browsers localStorage.
    if (localStorage.isToggled) {
      return JSON.parse(localStorage.isToggled);
     } else {
      return false;
    }
  }),
  ...
  actions: {
  ...
    expand: function() {
      localStorage.setItem('isToggled', JSON.stringify(true));
      this.set('isToggled', true);
    },
    contract: function() {
      localStorage.setItem('isToggled', JSON.stringify(false));
      this.set('isToggled', false);
    }
  ...
  }
});
```

Now when the page is reloaded the `isToggled` property state doesn't change to the initial state.

You can find the `isToggle` browsers localStorage variable in your browsers developer tool: `Application` -> `Local Storage` tab

Comment: Thanks, I ended up rewriting isToggled as a computed function  based on whether imapMailbox.username was set, but this answer definitely set me on the right path!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Ember Local Storage library to achieve this: https://github.com/funkensturm/ember-local-storage